# What is Runtime in Rust?

Tags: rust, runtime

I've read a blog. It says Rust doesn't not have built-in runtime. 
And I read a sentence in that blog:

> A runtime of your choosing, such as Tokio, async_std, smol, etc.

So what is the runtime in Rust?

Comment: In the context of async, the combination of reactor, executor, and other async components that need to cooperate with each other is often called [async] run-time. These are equivalent to what e.g. Python would call "event loops" - [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) (ships with Python), [trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [curio](https://curio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). The difference is that in Python one of those is officially blessed by being shipped with Python, so there's an "obvious" choice, which is (for good reasons) not the case in Rust.

Comment: Please **link** to the blog post you read this in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "the runtime" in Rust.

*A* runtime, in the context of your quote, is something which can execute asynchronous tasks / futures (an executor), usually bundled with utilities for synchronisation, IO, ...: while the Rust standard library contains the building blocks for asynchronous execution (a few traits and the `async` and `await` keywords) it provides no actual way to create, synchronise, or execute asynchronous tasks.